# Is there a way to tell how much time FindRoot is spending calculating Jacobians?

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning

I am solving a large number of trascendental equations by scanning [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) over a bunch of seeds and a bunch of different parameter values, and I would like to optimize the performance of this procedure.

I am solving for two complex variables in boxes in the complex plane, and I'm looking for the zeros of the derivatives of a known function $S(t,u)$ which can be relatively simple (`Leafcount`~80) or more of a handful to manage (`Leafcount`~6k). (The same problem as [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/23937/are-there-special-methods-for-solving-fz-0-for-analytic-f).) One thing I notice is that if I ask it to do the `Jacobian` using `FiniteDifference`s, at least on a single-run case, it will perform much faster than using the `Automatic` derivatives (which are symbolic, as the `Symbolic` setting does not produce a warning), and that this difference is more pronounced with the more complicated $S(t,u)$ is.

It seems relatively clear to me that each `FindRoot` instance is spending a lot of its time finding the symbolic derivative, so I am probably better off by calculating this separately and feeding it an explicit value.

Before I do that, though, **is there an easy way to confirm this hypothesis, and measure the time that `FindRoot` spends on symbolic differentiation before it gets a'Newtonning?**

This informs my future strategy, since if that fraction is large then this may be the only change I need to make, but if it's relatively small then it might be worthwhile pursuing other avenues first.

Moreover, some initial tests on using an explicit Jacobian fail to give particularly faster results. So, in addition to the above: what other factors could account for differences in timing between `Jacobian→Automatic` and `Jacobian→FiniteDifference`, and are there straightforward ways to diagnose them?

Comment: I don't understand a few things: if the argument to your `FindRoot` is `D[S[t,u],...]`, then it should be simple to pre-calculate that expression and feed it to `FindRoot` directly; if instead you refer to some symbolic pre-processing that `FindRoot` does, you can stop it by wrapping your symbolic function in a helper function in which each variable is protected by `?NumericQ`, so it can only be evaluated numerically. These two cases should allow you to test either one of your hypotheses in turn. If neither is the case, then please clarify your question with an example.